# Link between your sprites or game objects and Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a problem: in **`libgdx`** documentation about **`box2d`** ([libgdx box2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d)) in the section **`Sprites and Bodies`**, there is explanation how to set link between your sprites or game objects and Box2D, but when I'm trying to get **`setPosition`** method, I can't get it (my Entity object `e` has no such method like `setPosition`).

I don't understand which type of Entity I should use here (is it libgdx entity or Java entity class)?

**code**:

> In show() method

```
private Texture ballTexture = new Texture("images/ball.png");  
private Image ballImage = new Image(ballTexture);
body.setUserData(ballImage);
stage.add(ballImage);
```

> In render() method

```
// Create an array to be filled with the bodies
// (better don't create a new one every time though)
Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
// Now fill the array with all bodies
world.getBodies(bodies);

for (Body b : bodies) {
    // Get the body's user data - in this example, our user 
    // data is an instance of the Entity class
    Entity e = (Entity) b.getUserData();

    if (e != null) {
        // Update the entities/sprites position and angle
        e.setPosition(b.getPosition().x, b.getPosition().y);
        // We need to convert our angle from radians to degrees
        e.setRotation(MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * b.getAngle());
    }
}
stage.act();
stage.render();
```

---

I stopped at the line `e.setPosition(b.getPosition().x, b.getPosition().y);` because I can't get `setPosition()` method in `e` object. What may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below piece of code:

```
private Image ballImage = new Image(ballTexture);
body.setUserData(ballImage);
```

you set an object of type Image as user data.

This means that you should cast b.getUserData(); into Image, not Entity:

```
Image e = (Image) b.getUserData();
```

Image has setPosition and setRotation methods inherited from Actor.

Comment: Ok, guess you right. Can you explain how to cast into Image ? Please add to your answer the code from my question (**render() method**) and change it using `cast`?